# How smart are databases like MySQL and H2 when it comes to minimizing redundancy?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, h2, scalaquery

I'm new to databases, and this question has to do with how smart I can expect databases to be. Here by "databases" I mean "something like" MySQL or H2 (I actually have no idea if these two are similar, just that they are popular). I'm actually using ScalaQuery, so it abstracts away from the underlying database.

Suppose I have a table with entries of type (String, Int), with lots of redundancy in the String entries. So my table might look like:

(Adam, 18)
(Adam, 24)
(Adam, 34)
... continued ...
(Adam, 3492)
(Bethany, 4)
(Bethany, 45)
... continued ...
(Bethany, 2842)

If I store this table with H2, is it going to be smart enough to realize "Adam" and "Bethany" are repeated lots of times, and can be replaced with enumerations pointing to lookup tables? Or is it going to waste lots of storage?

Related: If H2 is smart in this respect with strings, is it also smart in the same way with doubles? In my probably brain-dead initial table, I happen to have lots of repeated double fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The database engine is not built to recognize redundancies in data and fix them. That is the task of the designer / developer.

Comment: Thanks. What are the services typically provided by a database engine? Having never studied DBs, I'm assuming some sort of caching and some sort of cross-indexing. Are these valid assumptions? Anything else using a DB buys me?

Comment: @emchristiansen I think it is time to get yourself a book about databases and actually study DBs. One can write a book trying to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Databases are designed to store information. There is no way database will know if (Adam, 44) and (Adam,55) can be compressed, and I would be petrified if databases tried to do things like you propose, as this can lead to a various performance and/or logical problems.

On the opposite, databases are not minimising the storage, they are adding redundant information, like indexes and keys, and other internal additional information required for DB.

DBs are built to retrieve information fast, not store it space-effectively. When it comes to complexity, database rather increase storage space, then decrease the performance of a query.

Answer (score 1):

There are some storage systems that compress pages, so the question is valid. I can't talk about MySQL, but I believe it is similar to H2. H2 isn't very smart in this regard. H2 does compress data, but only for the following cases:

- [LOB compression](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_compress_lob), if enabled.
- The following does not effect storage size of a *closed* database: H2 compresses the undo log when writing using [LZF](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/CompressTool.html) currently, therefore repeated data in a page will result in a slightly improved write performance (but only after a checkpoint). This may change in the future however.

Also, H2 uses a coded similar to UTF-8 to store text, but I wouldn't call this compression.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and other SQL products based on contiguous storage are not smart at this kind of thing at all.

Consider two logical sets, one referencing the other (i.e. a foreign key). One possible implementation is to physically store the value common to both sets just once and for both tables to store a pointer to the value (think reference type variables in 3GL programming languages such as C#). However, most SQL products physically store the value in both tables; if you want pointers then the end user has to implement them themselves, typically using autoincrement integer 'surrogate' keys, which sadly get exposed into the logical model.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are talking about data compression, which can be done by the database engine and shouldn't be your concern. 
Or you are talking about data normalization. Then you should read up on database design.

Databases are meant to store data, so no need to worry about a bit of redundancy. If you are going into several million lines and gigabytes of data, then you can start considering options. But up to that level you will not have any problems with performance.